# ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(1158)] handshake failed with ChromeDriver Chrome browser and Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When running my python selenium script with Chrome driver I get about three of the below error messages every time a page loads even though everything works fine. Is there a way to suppress these messages?

> [24412:18772:0617/090708:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(1158)]
> handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100

Comment: This could be a sign that the website requires a certificate which isn't in the certificate store of your web browser.  SSL has this certificate exchange handshake protocol that must pass before going any farther.

Comment: You can hide notifications of these errors as described in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74703248/14928633) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67876327/14928633).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You get this error when the browser asks you to accept the certificate from a website. You can set to ignore these errors by default in order avoid these errors.

For Chrome, you need to add ***--ignore-certificate-errors*** and
***--ignore-ssl-errors*** ChromeOptions() argument:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

For the Firefox, you need to set ***accept_untrusted_certs*** FirefoxProfile() option to True:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

For the Internet Explorer, you need to set ***acceptSslCerts*** desired capability:

```
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().INTERNETEXPLORER
capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True
driver = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=capabilities)
```

Comment: Is this still up-to-date? I'm trying the solution but still error is still coming through...

Comment: What does `1158` mean in `ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(1158)`? Is that the line number? I get the same error but instead of `1158` it's `968`. Also, none of the available solutions on SO work for me.

Answer (score 6):

This error message...

```
[ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(855)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
```

...implies that the **handshake failed** between *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* failed at some point.

### Root Cause Analysis

This error is generated due to [net::SSLClientSocketImpl::DoHandshake](https://code.woboq.org/data/symbol.html?root=../qt5/&ref=_ZN3net19SSLClientSocketImpl11DoHandshakeEv) and [net::SSLClientSocketImpl](https://code.woboq.org/data/symbol.html?root=../qt5/&ref=net::SSLClientSocketImpl) implemented in [ssl_client_socket_impl.cc
net::SSLClientSocketImpl::DoHandshake](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/net/socket/ssl_client_socket_impl.cc.html) as follows:

```
int SSLClientSocketImpl::DoHandshake() {
  crypto::OpenSSLErrStackTracer err_tracer(FROM_HERE);
  int rv = SSL_do_handshake(ssl_.get());
  int net_error = OK;
  if (rv <= 0) {
    int ssl_error = SSL_get_error(ssl_.get(), rv);
    if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_CHANNEL_ID_LOOKUP) {
      // The server supports channel ID. Stop to look one up before returning to
      // the handshake.
      next_handshake_state_ = STATE_CHANNEL_ID_LOOKUP;
      return OK;
    }
    if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP &&
    !ssl_config_.send_client_cert) {
      return ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED;
    }
    if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_PRIVATE_KEY_OPERATION) {
      DCHECK(ssl_config_.client_private_key);
      DCHECK_NE(kSSLClientSocketNoPendingResult, signature_result_);
      next_handshake_state_ = STATE_HANDSHAKE;
      return ERR_IO_PENDING;
    }
    OpenSSLErrorInfo error_info;
    net_error = MapLastOpenSSLError(ssl_error, err_tracer, &error_info);
    if (net_error == ERR_IO_PENDING) {
      // If not done, stay in this state
      next_handshake_state_ = STATE_HANDSHAKE;
      return ERR_IO_PENDING;
    }
    LOG(ERROR) << "handshake failed; returned " << rv << ", SSL error code "
           << ssl_error << ", net_error " << net_error;
    net_log_.AddEvent(
    NetLogEventType::SSL_HANDSHAKE_ERROR,
    CreateNetLogOpenSSLErrorCallback(net_error, ssl_error, error_info));
  }
  next_handshake_state_ = STATE_HANDSHAKE_COMPLETE;
  return net_error;
}
```

As per [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc handshake failed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395271) the main issue is the **failure** of **handshake** when *ChromeDriver* handshakes with **SSL pages** in *Chrome*. Though *Chromium* team conducts test for  *SSL handshake* through `net_unittests`, `content_tests`, and `browser_tests` but were not **exhaustive**. Some usecases are left out relying on the upstream tests.

### Conclusion

This error won't **interupt** the **execution** of your *Test Suite* and you can ignore this issue for the time being till it is fixed by the *Chromium Team*.

Answer (score 0):

For me it got resolved after writing code as below in chrome options, change from above answer was to include spki-list.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Nope doesn't change a thing

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this issue with Laravel and its Dusk browser testing suite, this is fixed by editing `tests/DuskTestCase.php` to add the `--ignore-certificate-errors` command-line switch:

```
   $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(collect([
       '--window-size=1920,1080',
       "--ignore-certificate-errors",
   ])->unless($this->hasHeadlessDisabled(), function ($items) {
         return $items->merge([
          '--disable-gpu',
          '--headless',
      ]);
   })->all());
```

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same problem. The problem was I did set `webdriver.chrome.driver` system property to chrome.exe. But one should download `chromedriver.exe` and set the file path as a value to `webdriver.chrome.driver` system property.

Once this is set, everything started working fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you elaborate how to do this, I'm not sure I follow

Comment: I downvoted this answer, because it does not provide enough specifics to be useful.  Please provide specific code example that you used to solve the problem.  I will then upvote your answer.

Answer (score -2):

ssl error means that the certificate is wrong and you should not allow execution or communication with a web address that is using a wrong ssl certificate. allow means that you accept the communication with a bogus or thief address and what ever comes when you communicate with them.
So it is not browser problem or something that you should fix by reprogramming your browser to allow failed ssl certificates.