# How to ignore ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(1061)] handshake failed in selenium c# ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have added

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list");
 options.AddArgument("--ignore-ssl-errors");
 options.AddArgument("test-type");
 options.AddArguments("-incognito");
 options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
 options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
 driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

But still getting:

```
ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(1061)] handshake failed error
```

How to suppress this error from console?

[image]

Comment: _Login Started_ and _Login successful_ being successful you need to update the question with more of your _binary versions_, code trials and relevant HTML.

Comment: code is working fine without errors but console is printing shown handshake failed errors, how to suppress  those errors from console

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
[ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(855)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -2
```

...implies that the **handshake failed** between *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* failed at some point.

---

### Root Cause

This error is generated due to [net::SSLClientSocketImpl::DoHandshake](https://code.woboq.org/data/symbol.html?root=../qt5/&ref=_ZN3net19SSLClientSocketImpl11DoHandshakeEv) and [net::SSLClientSocketImpl](https://code.woboq.org/data/symbol.html?root=../qt5/&ref=net::SSLClientSocketImpl) implemented in [ssl_client_socket_impl.cc
net::SSLClientSocketImpl::DoHandshake](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/net/socket/ssl_client_socket_impl.cc.html) as follows:

```
int SSLClientSocketImpl::DoHandshake() {
  crypto::OpenSSLErrStackTracer err_tracer(FROM_HERE);
  int rv = SSL_do_handshake(ssl_.get());
  int net_error = OK;
  if (rv <= 0) {
    int ssl_error = SSL_get_error(ssl_.get(), rv);
    if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_CHANNEL_ID_LOOKUP) {
      // The server supports channel ID. Stop to look one up before returning to
      // the handshake.
      next_handshake_state_ = STATE_CHANNEL_ID_LOOKUP;
      return OK;
    }
    if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP &&
    !ssl_config_.send_client_cert) {
      return ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED;
    }
    if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_PRIVATE_KEY_OPERATION) {
      DCHECK(ssl_config_.client_private_key);
      DCHECK_NE(kSSLClientSocketNoPendingResult, signature_result_);
      next_handshake_state_ = STATE_HANDSHAKE;
      return ERR_IO_PENDING;
    }
    OpenSSLErrorInfo error_info;
    net_error = MapLastOpenSSLError(ssl_error, err_tracer, &error_info);
    if (net_error == ERR_IO_PENDING) {
      // If not done, stay in this state
      next_handshake_state_ = STATE_HANDSHAKE;
      return ERR_IO_PENDING;
    }
    LOG(ERROR) << "handshake failed; returned " << rv << ", SSL error code "
           << ssl_error << ", net_error " << net_error;
    net_log_.AddEvent(
    NetLogEventType::SSL_HANDSHAKE_ERROR,
    CreateNetLogOpenSSLErrorCallback(net_error, ssl_error, error_info));
  }
  next_handshake_state_ = STATE_HANDSHAKE_COMPLETE;
  return net_error;
}
```

As per [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc handshake failed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395271) the main issue is the **failure** of **handshake** when *ChromeDriver* handshakes with **SSL pages** in *Chrome*. Though *Chromium* team conducts test for  *SSL handshake* through `net_unittests`, `content_tests`, and `browser_tests` but were not **exhaustive**. Some usecases are left out relying on the upstream tests.

### Conclusion

This error won't **interupt** the **execution** of your *Test Suite* and you can ignore this issue for the time being till it is fixed by the *Chromium Team*.

Comment: thank you! that's 2 years ago... error is still there...

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict Chromium's log level to 3, so that only fatal errors are logged. Please bear in mind that you won't see any other error-related messages which might cause mayhem in production! The code looks like this:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("log-level=3");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options : chromeOptions);
```

[Chromium log levels](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:content/public/common/content_switches.cc;l=541?q=kLoggingLevel&ss=chromium) are:

| Description | Value |
| --- | --- |
| INFO | 0 |
| WARNING | 1 |
| LOG_ERROR | 2 |
| LOG_FATAL | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter similar errors when using selenium
and can not fix it by `AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors")`.
solution:
1.`AddArgument("log-level=3")`,but this will not catch any error log
so you can catch error log by (try catch) like this
2.

```
try
{
   // your code
}
catch(Execption ex)
{
   console.writeline(ex.ToString())
}
```

Does anyone know of any unintended consequences if this is done?

Comment: Hello, please format your answer (you mixed the answer and the code). Thanks!