# Selenium ChromeDriver ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941) handshake failed

Tags: python, selenium, ssl, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently using Python3.7 under Windows 32-bit with Chrome Version 80.0.3987.100 under an enterprise controlled environment. It actually opens Chrome with the selected user profile but DevTools is not able to establish the connection, thus the code is interrupted before navigating to the selected url.
I've already checked for the correct version of ChromeDriver.

**My actual code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

woptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
woptions.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data2") 
woptions.add_argument("--profile-directory=pySelenium")
woptions.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
woptions.add_argument("--disable-default-apps")
woptions.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
woptions.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
woptions.add_argument("-no-sandbox")
woptions.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
woptions.add_argument("--dns-prefetch-disable")
woptions.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
woptions.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
woptions.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list")
woptions.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
woptions.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")
woptions.add_argument("--allow-insecure-localhost")
woptions.add_argument("--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests")
woptions.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension',False)

w = webdriver.Chrome(options=woptions)
w.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.uol.com.br")
```

**Error message:**

```
[12532:12892:0214/160407.330:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
```

followed by other errors which I think are derived from this one.

It seems I have to handle the SSL certificate somehow instead of just trying to ignore it, but I'm lost.

Comment: Interesting, I just got this for the first time too, and noticed you've just posted it.  Wonder if it's something new.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735756/how-to-ignore-ssl-client-socket-impl-cc1061-handshake-failed-in-selenium-c-sh/53756010#53756010) discussion helps you?

Comment: Actually, that discussion don't help because it does crashes and the test stops.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Selenium, python and Chrome80. What I've noticed is that those "ssl error code 1" appear simultaneously as some console errors, that have to do with some deprecation in Chrome. You might wanna check your console to see if it happens to you too

[image]

Comment: Due to enterprise's governance I do not have access to the console, but I'll try the help desk to check this.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and I was able to fix it by updating the OS time zone. 
In Windows 10, right-click the system clock in your Taskbar and select Adjust date/time.

I hope this helps.