# handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -201

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

i am trying to do web scraping using python using selenium but whenever i run the code i am getting the
error

```
[4824:524:0818/154954.605:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(959)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -201
[4824:524:0818/154954.614:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(959)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -201
[4824:524:0818/154954.721:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(959)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -201
[4824:524:0818/154954.730:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(959)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -201
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Rank, Country, Total Cases, New Cases, Deaths, New Deaths, Recovered, Active Cases, Critical]
Index: []
```

my code i am trying to use selenium to go at the website called worldometer and extract the data from the table present at their website using pandas. i have used selenium before to access other websites but it didn't give error then. I am using python version 3.6.8

i tried the fixes like installing OpenSSl but it didn't install
i also tried other fixes like adding --ignore-certificate-errors and --ignore-ssl-errors but that didn't work also

```
import pandas as pd
import time

# Covid 19 Webscraper

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe')

# opening sites

browser.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
time.sleep(15)

#creating Data Frame

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Rank','Country','Total Cases','New Cases','Deaths','New Deaths','Recovered','Active Cases','Critical'])

# finding xpath and info

for i in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='main_table_countries_today']/tbody/tr"):
    td_list = i.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    row = []
    for td in td_list:
        row.append(td.text)
    data={}
    for j in range(len(df.columns)):
        data[df.columns[j]] = row[j]
    
    df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: Screenshots are not accessible for all users. Please copy-paste the error text as code and remove the screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its look like your browser store don't have certificate required by website. Please use chrome options as below:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-error")
options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe',options=options)
browser.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
```

With Capabilites:

```
caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
caps['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
caps['acceptSslCerts'] = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
```

Comment: Funny thing is I am not getting any error and using same code :P . can you please try once more with updated answer (Using Capabilities ). Also please check your python and chromedriver version. I am using 3.8.0 and 84.0.xxx respectively.

Comment: i am also using the same version and run the updated code twice but still giving error

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65906969/14928633):

> The error is know to the [Chromium] developer team (or broadly speaking, it has been reported on multiple occasions).

So, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735756/how-to-ignore-ssl-client-socket-impl-cc1061-handshake-failed-in-selenium-c-sh#answer-67876327) (Explanatory note: I changed the code to Python 3 and Selenium 4. The important line is marked with ), you can set Chromium [`log-level`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#log-level) to hide error:

> You can restrict Chromium's log level to 3, so that only fatal errors are logged. Please bear in mind that you won't see any other error-related messages which might cause mayhem in production! The code looks like this:
>
> ```
> from selenium import webdriver
> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
>
> service_current = Service(r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
> options_current = Options()
> options_current.binary_location = r"C:\path\to\chrome.exe"
> options_current.add_argument("log-level=3") # 
>
> browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_current, options=options_current)
> ```
>
> [Chromium log levels](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:content/public/common/content_switches.cc;l=541?q=kLoggingLevel&ss=chromium) are:
>
> | Description | Value |
> | --- | --- |
> | INFO | 0 |
> | WARNING | 1 |
> | LOG_ERROR | 2 |
> | LOG_FATAL | 3 |