# Selenium ssl_client_socket_impl.cc handshake failed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am receiving this error while testing with Selenium

```
[18912:1216:0116/175151.966:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
```

My current code is

```
settings = {
      'proxy':{
          'https':'https://' + proxy 
      }
    }
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=settings, chrome_options=options)
```

Is there any other way to ignore/solve this error?

Comment: What is the issue you have? Does this message change anything?

Comment: When you press submit through selenium this error blocks the request that wouldve normally went to the api, for example if I were to hit submit on a register form the request won't go through because of this error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to a list of [command line switches for Chromium](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) ([which works for your case](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities)) you need to use `--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list` as a webdriver option argument.

Your code snippet `options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')` implements this in a correct way (*cf.* [doc](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.options), respectively the [code base of Chromium](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/) for [`kIgnoreCertificateErrorsSPKIList[]`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:services/network/public/cpp/network_switches.cc;l=35)). On a slight off-topic note, `--ignore-certificate-errors` (as suggested in various [StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507078/how-to-deal-with-certificates-using-selenium)) is [deprecated](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Anyhow, generally speaking your error message (*see below*)

> [18912:1216:0116/175151.966:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101

infers that the handshake between your Selenium ChromeDriver and the Chrome Browser has failed along the way of execution. If we take a look at [`ssl_client_socket_impl.cc`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/net/socket/ssl_client_socket_impl.cc), we can see [`SSLClientSocketImpl::DoHandshake()`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/net/socket/ssl_client_socket_impl.cc#894) (*which causes your error*):

```
int SSLClientSocketImpl::DoHandshake() {
  crypto::OpenSSLErrStackTracer err_tracer(FROM_HERE);
  int rv = SSL_do_handshake(ssl_.get());
  int net_error = OK;
  if (rv <= 0) {
    int ssl_error = SSL_get_error(ssl_.get(), rv);
    if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP && !send_client_cert_) {
      return ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED;
    }
    if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_PRIVATE_KEY_OPERATION) {
      DCHECK(client_private_key_);
      DCHECK_NE(kSSLClientSocketNoPendingResult, signature_result_);
      next_handshake_state_ = STATE_HANDSHAKE;
      return ERR_IO_PENDING;
    }
    if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_CERTIFICATE_VERIFY) {
      DCHECK(cert_verifier_request_);
      next_handshake_state_ = STATE_HANDSHAKE;
      return ERR_IO_PENDING;
    }
    OpenSSLErrorInfo error_info;
    net_error = MapLastOpenSSLError(ssl_error, err_tracer, &error_info);
    if (net_error == ERR_IO_PENDING) {
      // If not done, stay in this state
      next_handshake_state_ = STATE_HANDSHAKE;
      return ERR_IO_PENDING;
    }
    LOG(ERROR) << "handshake failed; returned " << rv << ", SSL error code "
               << ssl_error << ", net_error " << net_error;
    NetLogOpenSSLError(net_log_, NetLogEventType::SSL_HANDSHAKE_ERROR,
                       net_error, ssl_error, error_info);
  }
  next_handshake_state_ = STATE_HANDSHAKE_COMPLETE;
  return net_error;
}
```

*As mentioned previously, the main issue is the failure of a handshake - specifically when ChromeDriver requests a handshake with a SSL page in Chrome. The error is know to the developer team (or broadly speaking, it has been reported on multiple occasions).*

---

You can't fix this bug, unfortunately! Luckily, the error won't interrupt your program whatsoever. If you're bothered only by the messages themselves, feel free to compress all warning messages via `options.add_argument('log-level=INT')`, whereas `INT` might be one of the documented log-levels:

> log-level:
> Sets the minimum log level. Valid values are from 0 to 3:
>
> ```
> INFO = 0, 
> WARNING = 1, 
> LOG_ERROR = 2, 
> LOG_FATAL = 3.
> ```
>
> default is 0.

*Quote taken from [this StackOverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744968/how-to-suppress-console-error-warning-info-messages-when-executing-selenium-pyth)*

Thus you can use `options.add_argument('log-level=3')` to supress all kind of infos, warnings, errors or fatal messages *(might suggest using only level 2 for errors)*. Please bear in mind that you won't see any other error-related messages which might cause mayhem in production!

Comment: @sleep Please let me know whether anything was unclear or if I shall go in-depth into a certain topic! I hope my reply helped you out. :-)

Comment: I'm seeing the same errors with Edge and the Edge driver. Since Edge is also based in Chromium, does this bug also affect the Edge driver?