# Selenium Web automation

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I was automating the times jobs search portal using selenium. This is my code :-

```
`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)

os.environ['PATH'] += 'C:/Users/sunil/OneDrive/Desktop/web'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
driver.get('https://www.timesjobs.com')

driver.maximize_window()

skill_search = driver.find_element('xpath',
                                   '//div[@class = "auto-suggest-blk"]/input[@name = "txtKeywords"]')

skill_search.send_keys('Python')

loc_search = driver.find_element('xpath',
                                   '//div/input[@name = "txtLocation"]')
loc_search.send_keys('Mumbai')

exp_search = Select(driver.find_element('xpath', '//div[@class = "srch-select"]/select[@name = "cboWorkExp1"]'))
exp_search.select_by_visible_text('2 years')

find_jobs = driver.find_element('xpath',
                                '//button[@class = "waves-effect waves-light btn"]')
find_jobs.click()`
```

While running the program, it ran successfully but it also gave some errors about which I have no idea. Please try to help with these errors.

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63822/devtools/browser/205737d2-1edc-48b1-9654-e3e120e8201c
[20160:5272:0727/092026.844:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
[20160:5272:0727/092026.929:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
[13840:22560:0727/092032.720:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(701)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for tracking.sokrati.com failed:
----- Certificate i=0 (CN=*.sokrati.com,OU=Technology,O=Sokrati Technologies Pvt Ltd,L=Pune,ST=Maharashtra,C=IN) -----
ERROR: Time is after notAfter


[20160:5272:0727/092032.721:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -201
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63467388/8669719