# Powershell and selenium chromedriver getting SSL error opening website

Tags: powershell, selenium

I get an ssl error trying to get the chromedriver to launch. Not sure if its the options Im using or what.  WebDriver 3.14 
ChromeDriver downloaded from here
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home 
Using Chrome 87

Browsing to the website manually and inspecting the SSL cert, it looks fine.

Running the powershell script below, website opens, but in the terminal, I see the following ssl-related errors.   Am I missing something?

> ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1,
> SSL error code 1, net_error -100

Powershell code

```
$workingPath = 'D:\tools\Selenium'
# Add the working directory to the environment path.
# This is required for the ChromeDriver to work.
if (($env:Path -split ';') -notcontains $workingPath) {
    $env:Path += ";$workingPath"
}    
# Import Selenium to PowerShell
Import-Module "$($workingPath)\WebDriver.dll"

#-- options
$ChromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions    
$ChromeOptions.AcceptInsecureCertificates = $True  
$ChromeOptions.AddArguments(@(
    "--disable-extensions",
    "--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection",
    "--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist",
    "--disable-download-protection",
    "--disable-notifications",
    "--ignore-certificate-errors",
    "--ignore-ssl-errors"))
# Create a new ChromeDriver Object instance.
$ChromeDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions)

# Launch a browser and go to URL
$ChromeDriver.Navigate().GoToURL('https://weburl.here.com/')
```

Comment: What if you try this selenium powershell module https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735756/how-to-ignore-ssl-client-socket-impl-cc1061-handshake-failed-in-selenium-c-sh/53756010#53756010) answer help you?

Comment: @DebanjanB - yes, I think so.