# Laravel dusk Your connection is not private

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

We recently decided our project is getting too large to function well without automated tests.
While trying to write our first Laravel Dusk test for the project I found the test failing without a clear reason.

First I noticed a weird line about the SSL handshake failing but after a little bit of searching, this error wasn't getting me anywhere.

[image: ssl client socked handshake failed]

After a while, I found the option to run dusk in a way it showed the browser and its actions.
Turns out my test was failing because the page it was visiting was never shown because of chrome's "Your connection is not private" page.

[image]

Then I found this post from 2017 https://laravel-news.com/chrome-63-now-forces-dev-domains-https
According to this post chrome shouldn't show this page when you are using .localhost or other unused domain extensions, I have tried the extensions .local .localhost & .test but none were successful.

Is there a way to tell chrome I don't want to see this page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the other answer, which didn't provide enough detail for me, this is fixed by editing `tests/DuskTestCase.php` to add the `--ignore-certificate-errors` command-line switch:

```
   $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(collect([
       '--window-size=1920,1080',
       "--ignore-certificate-errors",
   ])->unless($this->hasHeadlessDisabled(), function ($items) {
         return $items->merge([
          '--disable-gpu',
          '--headless',
      ]);
   })->all());
```

Note that only the `--ignore-certificate-errors` option seems to be required - as far as I can tell `--ignore-ssl-errors` currently has no effect at all, at least for this issue.

Answer (score 7):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42340168/1014941) to a similar question regarding using Selenium/ChromeDriver with Python points to the solution.

You need to create your ChromeDriver with the following flags:

```
--ignore-certificate-errors
--ignore-ssl-errors
```

For Laravel Dusk these are set in `DuskTestCase::driver()` (`DuskTestCase.php` is in the `tests\Browser` directory)