# Errors with SSL verification with my python webscraping program using selenium and chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, ssl, selenium-webdriver

I have just started another class for my program I am making to help with school and have run into many errors that all seem to be connected to the website requiring **SSL verification**. This is currently my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class ratingBot:

    def __init__ (self):
       #ignoring ssl verifications through chrome webdriver options

        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()
        teacher='Jason Yalim'
        self.driver.get('https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search.jsp?queryoption=HEADER&queryBy=teacherName&schoolName=Arizona+State+University&schoolID=45&query=jennie+si')
        sleep(4)
        driver.get('/html/body/div[10]/button[1]').click()
        sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchr"]').send_keys(teacher)

mybot=ratingBot()
```

and these are the errors I am getting. Keep in mind that everything is up to date an I have set my chromedriver in my windows PATHS

```
[16436:16516:1214/210007.796:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [21:00:07.796] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[16056:25032:1214/210013.515:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -113
[16056:25032:1214/210013.759:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -113
[16056:25032:1214/210018.171:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -113
[16056:25032:1214/210018.354:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -113
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR:ssl\_client\_socket\_openssl.cc(1158)\] handshake failed with ChromeDriver Chrome browser and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883759/errorssl-client-socket-openssl-cc1158-handshake-failed-with-chromedriver-chr)