# I am using python selenium for web crawling "href" from a html page. But I am facing this handshake error

Tags: python, php, laravel, selenium, laravel-artisan

I am using python selenium for web crawling/scraping "href" from a html page. But I am facing this some handshake error when I run the Laravel artisan command because I want to save all my crawled/scraped "hrefs" in mysql database

**MY PYTHON CODE::**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get("https://www.telemart.pk/mobile-and-tablets.html")
time.sleep(5)

elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".col-sm-3.box [href]")
for element in elements:
print(element.get_attribute("href"))
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="result"]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[4]/a').click()
time.sleep(10)
browser.close()
```

**MY PHP ARTISAN COMMAD HANDLE::**

```
public function handle()
{
    $telemartProductRepository = new TelemartProductsRepository();
        $filePath = 'C:\Users\udotb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe 
               D:/xampp/htdocs/price-watch/modules/crawler/PK/telemart/products.py';
        $telemart = exec("$filePath 2>&1", $err);
        $result = $telemartProductRepository->storeProducts($telemart, self::VENDOR_ID, '7');
        echo $result['status'];
    }
```

**AND ERROR I AM FACING::**

```
[6884:13420:0121/103241.511:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [10:32:41.511] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection:
A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[6884:13420:0121/103241.616:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [10:32:41.616] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection:
A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[6884:13420:0121/103241.621:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [10:32:41.621] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1073 Getting Default Adapter failed.
[13900:13600:0121/103245.030:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
[13900:13600:0121/103245.030:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
[13900:13600:0121/103245.156:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
```

Comment: Seems like you could just ignore these errors. Does this SO question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883759/errorssl-client-socket-openssl-cc1158-handshake-failed-with-chromedriver-chr

Comment: I can ignore but it is not working.