# Selenium ChromeDriver error while loading page

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

*I've tried this code and got* **[ handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101 ]**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
url = "https://linkum.ru/"

try:
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#rec143282558 > div > nav > div.header__auth > a").click()
    time.sleep(2)
except Exception as err:
    print(err)

finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBOjB.png)

Comment: Seems like the question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883759/errorssl-client-socket-openssl-cc1158-handshake-failed-with-chromedriver-chr

Comment: thank you so much <3